# Can't get elements from database twice

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, junit

I'm testing DAO layer in Spring MVC + Hibernate + HSQLDB and I'm not able to load playlist twice from database.

I don't know why I get size of `List` as 0. Method `testSavePlaylist` is successful, but method `test_getPlaylistById` fails. When I test only one method it's working great.

**Error Trace:**

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<2> but was:<0>
at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:743)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:118)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:555)
at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:542)
at adrian.example.musicplayer.dao.music.PlayListImplDaoTest.test_getPlaylistById(PlayListImplDaoTest.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:74)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:83)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:72)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

**Junit Class**

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@WebAppConfiguration
@ContextConfiguration
@Transactional
public class PlayListImplDaoTest {

    @Autowired
    PlayListDao playlistDao;

    private static boolean setUpIsDone = false;

    @Before
    public  void setUp() throws Exception {
        if(setUpIsDone) {
            return;
        }
        this.playlistDao.savePlaylistForJunit();

        setUpIsDone = true;
    }

    @Test
    public void  test_getPlaylistById() throws InterruptedException {
        List<Playlist> testedPlaylist = (List<Playlist>) this.playlistDao.getPlaylistById(1);
        assertEquals(2, testedPlaylist.size());
    }

    @Test
    public void testSavePlaylist() throws InterruptedException {
        this.playlistDao.savePlaylist(1, "TestPlaylist2");
        List<Playlist> testedPlaylist2 = (List<Playlist>) this.playlistDao.getPlaylistById(1);
        assertEquals(2, testedPlaylist2.size());
    }
}
```

Comment: Also, rather than using a `boolean` variable to keep your `setUp()` from running more than once, use `@BeforeClass` annotation instead of `@Before`. That way it's only run once for the entire class before any tests, instead of once before each test method.

Comment: @t0mppa `@BeforeClass` is not usefull for this case because method `setUp()` needs an instance variable playlistDao obtained (autowired) from fully initialized application context. Therefore `setUp()` can not be static.

Comment: @LukasRisko: Good catch, I would just add in direct DB manipulation into the test class though, instead of having my DAO filled with code used for testing only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe, the default behavior for transactional JUnit tests in spring is to rollback after each test. Therefore, the once off DB population you do in `setUp()` gets rolled back after the first test, leading to the 2nd test failing because the database is now empty.

You could reverse this behavior by annotating the test class with `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=false)`.

However, it can be considered a bad practice to have stateful tests, whereby data is persisted after one test, with the potential to impact the results of the next and to yield different results based on the execution order.

Instead, you may be better off removing the "if" from your `setUp()` and re-populating your DB anew for each test pass.

Answer (score 3):

You annotated your class as `@Transactional`, what means that every `@Test` method will be executed within a transaction. Method annotated with `@Before` is executed before each of test method, but within the same transaction as the test method. Be aware of the fact that `@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback = true)` is default for test environment. So if you run your tests one of many possible scenarios is:

1. a new transaction is open
2. whole `setUp()` is executed what means that some test data are created using `this.playlistDao.savePlaylistForJunit()` and after that the flag `setUpIsDone` is set to true
3. `testSavePlaylist()` is executed succesfully as there are test data available
4. the transaction is rolled back what means that test data created by `this.playlistDao.savePlaylistForJunit()` is gone
5. a new transaction is open
6. setUp method is early returned as `setUpIsDone` is true at this point
7. `test_getPlaylistById()` is executed but there is no test data available
8. the transaction is rolled back

For more information look at [the section Spring Testing Annotations of the Spring Reference Documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#integration-testing-annotations-spring)